# Show variable data attribute values based on changing selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, custom-data-attribute

In my current snippet, you will see the div `<p class="package-cost">$xx</p>` with static pricing. Then within the same parent element, there is an input like this: `<input type="checkbox" class="tp-pack-check" data-solo-price="10" data-combined-price="8">` with multiple data prices.

I am able to map out the selected value from these checkboxes and then display the appropriate data attribute, but this is all based on another change function.

I am wanting to display into the `.package-cost` div the price, based on the package selection. If package1 and 2 are both selected, then each `.tp-package` will get the appropriate `data-combined-price`........... but if the only a single package is selected, such as package2 the `.package-cost` for each `.tp-package` will use the `data-solo-price` attribute to display.

**Please note - to reduce code, I only posted the div for package 2. So either select package 2 by itself or package 1 and 2 together.

I know the mapping function in my code does not relate to this specific question. I just wanted to show how I did it for that case.

Summarize...

If package 1 and package are selected, the pricing within `.package-cost` should be:

-8

-13

-18

If only package 2 is selected, the pricing within `.package-cost` should be:

-10

-15

-20

```js
var pgReview = $('#pg-review');
var tpReview = $('#tp-review');
$('.product-check').on('change', function () {
  if ($('#package1').is(':checked') && $('#package2').is(':checked')) {
    $('#tp-package-wrap').show();
    $('#pack-1').show();
  }
  else if ($('#package1').is(':checked')) {
    $('#tp-package-wrap').hide();
    $('#pack-1').show();
  }
  else if ($('#package2').is(':checked')) {
    $('#tp-package-wrap').show();
    $('#pack-1').hide();
  }
});
if ($('#package1').is(':checked') && $('#package2').is(':checked')) {
  var price1 = $('.tp-pack-check:checked').map(function() {
    return "$" + $(this).data('combined-price');
  }).toArray().join(" ");
  tpReview.html(price1);
} else {
  if ($('#package2').is(':checked')) {
    var price = $('.tp-pack-check:checked').map(function() {
      return "$" + $(this).data('solo-price');
    }).toArray().join(" ");
    tpReview.html(price);
  } else if ($('#package1').is(':checked')) {
    console.log("Price - Package 2");
  }
}
```

```css
#pack-1, #tp-package-wrap {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="product-check" id="package1">
<input type="checkbox" class="product-check" id="package2">
<div id="pg-review"></div>
<div id="tp-review"></div>
<div id="pack-1">
<p>Package 1 Section</p>
</div>
<div id="tp-package-wrap">
  <div class="tp-package">
    <div class="product-wrap">
      <label for="tp-bronze" class="package-check-toggle tp-package-push">
                                    <h2 class="tp-package-title">A</h2>
                                    <p class="package-cost">$10</p>
                                </label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="tp-pack-check" data-solo-price="10" data-combined-price="8">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-package">
    <div class="product-wrap">
      <label for="tp-silver" class="package-check-toggle tp-package-push">
                                    <h2 class="tp-package-title">B</h2>
                                    <p class="package-cost">$15</p>
                                </label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="tp-pack-check" data-solo-price="15" data-combined-price="13">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tp-package">
    <div class="product-wrap">
      <label for="tp-gold" class="package-check-toggle tp-package-push">
                                    <h2 class="tp-package-title">C</h2>
                                    <p class="package-cost">$20</p>
                                </label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="tp-pack-check" data-solo-price="20" data-combined-price="18" data-package="Gold">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *I know the mapping function in my code does not relate to this specific question.* Why are you not showing the code which *does* relate to this specific question? Also, please read how to create a [mcve]. You likely don't need this much code to show the issue you're having, and you might find your problem by reducing the problem.

Comment: "I just wanted to show how I did it for that case" I wanted to show how I obtained the value before and used it in a different manner. I took the price, based on selection and then displayed it. I left it there, like I said to show how I got it to work with a different scenario to possibly help someone.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I know how to post a question. I do not need help with that. I stated IN  my question as to why I kept it in there. I reduced my code from thousands of lines to that little snippet you see above. I wouldn't leave unnecessary code in for no reason. I likely DO need all of the code shown in my question..the small , couple of lines I left in are to possibly help someone understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: Then you just want someone to write the code for you, based on this snippet of code?

Comment: I am asking for help as to how I go about it. This is the point I am stuck. If I knew how to progress and write more code for it, I would.